# Finding coefficient of vector expression when using SuperLie package

Tags: vector, algebra

I'm using the SuperLie package and using that have defined a Lie superalgebra with an ordered basis:

```
Needs["SuperLie`"]

pslAlgebra[V, Dim -> {4, 4}];

B=Basis[V];
```

I then have various expressions that are linear combinations of these basis elements and I want a function that extracts the coefficient to a chosen basis vector in that expression.

I tried a few naive things with the Coefficient function and several other similar methods, however this returns the wrong thing; the following should return 3/4, but instead returns 0:

```
Coefficient[Act[B[[38]],B[[4]]],B[[10]]]
```

From what I can tell it appears to treat linear combinations of vectors as a single variable. I think this is something to do with the type of objects these basis vectors are defined as.

Can anyone suggest a function or work around to this?

Thank you!

EDIT: the documentation for the SuperLie package explains that objects are defined as "vector", "scalar" or "common/undecided" which I suspect changes how the Coefficient function views these. I tried using the "UnVector" and "Scalar" functions to declare my expressions to be different types of objects but this did not work and just returned errors.